# LinkedIn Avatar 403 Response

Tags: oauth, http-status-code-404, linkedin-api, avatar, httpforbiddenhandler

We’re seeing intermittent 403s from the media.licdn.com 4 server - some users can see the avatar, but others get a 403 at the exact same URL.

I know this is fundamentally a LinkedIn issue, but since the Auth0 plugin is borrowing these images, any insight on why this might be happening or if perhaps there is a more stable image URL that should be used instead?

Example:

```
https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_xfyAKR4RCit_89KnV18tTuHYCgxEknxzV68c35dR1lPozspzp18BrGHRtg0FQsxv0S8tTfWY3IO7cb8U4kDYbhdjnIOfcbDnMkDYq34UiI-7cb-gZlhvQzXc8rGiQAyj2xAO-VZNny76NijVo3Hf1E
```